# CakePHP testAction does not correctly uses the resource routes

Tags: cakephp, testing, routes

currently I'm writing the controller tests for a part of my application (using CakePHP 2.3.0 Stable). I am having a strange problem with the URL for the **testAction()** method.

The following works:

```
$this->testAction('/users/index');
```

And this does not:

```
$this->testAction('/users');
```

If I don't add the exact controller action I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: users
Test case: UsersControllerTest(testIndex)
```

All of the routes are generated via

```
Router::mapResources('users');
```

The strange thing is, calling **/users** in a browser works perfectly. I have the same problem when testing my API. Calling **/users.json** in the browser works, for the tests it doesn't.

Currently I use **/users/index.json** to make the tests pass, but there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that, because you're using RESTful interface, that the request method (get/post/put) needs to be declared explicitly? No idea, just thinking out loud. Will need to check the source code to see how testAction() is routed (is it fully handled via the Routes?)